# React:Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am creating a simple react calendar using full calendar and google calendar API, am using the following official documents [full calendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar), here is the official demo [live demo](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010)

Here is a functional component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { Calendar as FullCalendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

const Calendar = () => {
    const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState('');
    const calendarRef = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (calendarRef.current) {
             console.log(calendarRef);
            setCalendar(new FullCalendar(calendarRef.current, {
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
                  },              
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYKEY',
            }));        
        }
    }, [calendarRef.current]);

    // console.log(calendar);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Jestm Calendar</h1>
            <div ref={calendarRef}>{calendar}</div>

        </div>
    )
}


export default Calendar;
```

Now when I run my app,  iam getting the following error `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check it [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) `FullCalendar` is a React Component. You don't need to initialize it with `new`, instead use `<FullCalendar />` and it should work.

Comment: @SonuBamniya what about google calendar? do I just need to call a plugin or what?

Comment: @SonuBamniya read here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: You can pass every property as `props`. So, for your case, you should call `<FullCalendar 
plugins= [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin] header= {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
                  } googleCalendarApiKey= 'MYKEY', />`

Comment: did you even try that or your just guessing?

Comment: I have used FullCalendar on the enterprise level. Though I have not integrated the google-calendar inside it, but can assume it is the way it should be.
If doing this way, I guess you should call render method of calendar. `<div ref={calendarRef}>{calendar.render()}</div>`

Comment: @SonuBamniya app.js?1:120892 Uncaught TypeError: calendar.render is not a function
    at Calendar (app.js?1:120892)

Comment: Yes, because the initial state of the `calendar` is a string, not an Object. Try adding a conditional operator. `<div ref={calendarRef}>{calendar && calendar.render ? calendar.render(): null}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to print the `FullCalendar` Object directory in the `render`.

```
 return (
        <div>
            <h1>Jestm Calendar</h1>
            <div ref={calendarRef}>{calendar && calendar.render ? calendar.render() : null}</div>

        </div>
    )
```